# Unable to hit enter after entering text

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I want to hit enter or click on the elemen, i am able to send the text to the text field by using, sendKeys, after that i want to hit enter to accept the content, but i am unable to do so, i am using iphone simulator
This is what i have tried

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement().click(); //not working
 driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);//not working
 driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);//not working
```

This is my code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypeNavigationBar[@name='IPAssetView']/XCUIElementTypeButton[3]")).click();
            driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Category").click();
            driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("my Text");
            driver.switchTo().activeElement().click();
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("\n");` or you can do `driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("my Text"+"\n");` also can try `driver.press_keycode(66)`

Comment: Thanks for the info, however i tried that as well and for some reason it is not working, i noticed that my app creates dynamic elements. so i think i failed to ask the correct question. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my app created dynamic elements so therefore i was not able to inspect them using appium inspector session, this is how i finally handled that.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource()); // to see the content of the page
```

After i saw the content i realized that it was creating a dynamic name so i just just that element for clicking, at the end my code is as following.

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("Category").click();
            driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("My Text"  );
            driver.findElement(By.name("My Text")).click(); // so basically the dropdown creates the same name that i sent to the text field XD makes sense.
```